# How to share custom data between iPhone applications?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

If I make two iPhone applications, how can/should I share custom data (not contacts and stuff like that) among them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are two different ways you might go about this.

1) The data you need to share is non-persistent. In other words you need to launch one application with a piece of data that it can do something with. In this case you would register a special URL scheme per application.

You can find out more information about URL schemes via Craig Hockenberry in his [[redacted] blog post](http://furbo.org/2008/10/01/redacted/).

2) The data you need to share is persistent. In other words you need something like a data file that both applications can read and write too. As far as I know there isn't a safe way to do this other than storing your data on a remote server. If you need the data accessible without a data connection then you would need to figure out a way to sync data between the individual apps and the remote server.

Answer (score 19):

In addition to what's already been mentioned, the iPhone documentation on code signing seems to imply that applications signed with the same identity can access the same Keychain items. If you need to store relatively small amounts of data (passwords, etc), this may be a useful technique.

Comment: Yes after Micheal Ledford's answer, which is correct as far as I know, I began looking into the Keychain, I'm not sure how to get the signing right yet, but it might be a solution to share small data (precisely passwords) among applications.

Comment: I've not tried it yet, but this looks like the keychain step-by-step: http://shaune.com.au/ios-keychain-sharing-data-between-apps/

Answer (score 5):

Apps can share a container directory on iCloud.

From [Apple's doc on configuring your iCloud entitlements](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/iCloud/iCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW1):

> The iCloud Containers field identifies the list of container
>   directories that your app can access in the user’s iCloud storage.
>   (This field corresponds to the
>   com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers entitlement.) The
>   strings you add to this list must correspond to bundle identifiers for
>   apps created by your team. Xcode uses the current app’s bundle
>   identifier to specify the first string; you can change this to a
>   different bundle identifier if you want multiple apps to share a main
>   container directory. You can also add additional bundle identifiers
>   for your team’s other apps.

Answer (score 3):

Dan Grisby's [most recent mobile orchard podcast](http://www.mobileorchard.com/podcast-warm-clothed-and-fed-developer-run-iphone-businesses/) hypothesizes that you might also use custom named clipboards to share information between apps. I realize this is an older post, but I thought I would point this out because it's high on google results.  :)

(Documentation also suggests that `NSUserDefaults` might be useful here, but I've [read elsewhere](http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2009/03/iphone-dev-suite-preferences-fail-to-deliver-on-iphone.ars) that that's actually not the case.)

Answer (score 3):

A hack I can think of is [writing to and reading from the Address Book](http://techelp.in/mobile/?p=4), with the API, storing data in the available fields (+ NSData conversion for the user image perhaps). Edit: I've successfully implemented the NSData conversion and storing of objects inside a contact's display image, thus making them non-editable from the contacts application.

Comment: +1 for a nice trick, but I expect the end user might be annoyed about having garbage in their address book.

Comment: @sbwoodside Not to worry, we'll pack an Ativan pill with the application, so he'll be less annoyed. On a serious note, I chose the path that offers the full functionality asked about in the question... this comes, as always, with the reminder "be careful what you wish for, you might just get it", in this case, with the mild annoyance of a seemingly blank address book record.

Comment: cant you store this data in image of already existent contact? like appending garbage or to EXIF