# Accessing iphone maps bookmarks through SDK

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, google-maps

Does anyone know of a way to access the bookmarks of the "Maps" application programmatically through the SDK? I'd like to read and write bookmarks if possible. Ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am pretty sure the answer is no.  I considered two possible solutions:

- Can you access the data persisted by the Maps app directly

There isn't a generic way of [sharing data between apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220630/how-to-share-custom-data-between-iphone-applications), so a **no** for this approach.

- Can you access the bookmarks through the new 3.0 [MapKit Framework](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/).

**No**.  Unless I have missed it.  It doesn't look like the MapKit exposes this functionality.

Comment: You're completely right, the answer is a big "no". (As a side note, Apple doesn't even allow the programatic setting of the users' wallpaper. Access is limited for "security reasons", I would assume the same here. A possible exploit is looking for a bookmark named "Home" and storing that location on a server, then selling that information.)