# What are the available data sharing scheme between two iPhone apps?

Tags: iphone, uikit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to share custom data between iPhone applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220630/how-to-share-custom-data-between-iphone-applications)

Aside from using URL scheme, what other means are there for two iPhone apps to pass data between each other (ideally, without launching another app -- which is one of the downsides using URL scheme)

Comment: See thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220630/how-to-share-custom-data-between-iphone-applications

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately apps are sandboxed, and can't communicate with each other.  You would have to implement something server-side to act as a central location for this data.