# How to share data between applications?

Tags: ios, iphone, share

I have previously developed on Android but never on iPhone so my question could be stupid for iPhone developers.

***Does it exist one or several ways to share data between applications on iPhone ?***

In Android, data sharing between applications could be performed thanks to ContentProvider.

I found a post ( [How to share custom data between iPhone applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220630/how-to-share-custom-data-between-iphone-applications) ) that talks about URL scheme but it seems only usable to share small piece of data.

Answer (score 1):

Your conclusions based on the question you linked to are correct; there's no way for iPhone applications to communicate like on Android.  As mentioned, you can send information from one app to another via the URL scheme, or you may share some Keychain information amongst your own apps if you sign them properly.

Answer (score 0):

No - iPhone apps are sandboxed and cannot share information.  The few exceptions are that you can access information from some of the Apple apps such as the photo library, calendar, email and contacts.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to share, if it is contained in a document for example, then if another application supports the document format, then you can impliment a control in your application that will allow you to open it in another app. i think it is a UIDocumentController, or UIDocumentInteractionController.
Im not 100% on the class name but good reader uses this method as does iBook, to open PDF files from another application.