# How to access the notes from note application from another application in ios?

Tags: ios

Hi I am working on an application with features to show the notes from note application or push a note.
I don't see any sample or tutorials regarding this. Would really appreaciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about the built-in Note application, you cannot. That's the whole idea behind app sandboxing.

(In some cases notes are saved in an IMAP mailbox, and you could access that. But they don't have to be in IMAP.)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question and answer: [How to share custom data between iPhone applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220630/how-to-share-custom-data-between-iphone-applications)

its more general than what you are asking for but it should work.