# Storing shared data for iPhones

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a question: how is it possible to get application A action results in application B? Moreover, application A can be deleted, but the results should be saved.  The data represents a small set of numbers. As far as I know, ios has an ability to save data in the storage that does not depend on the application. Or, probably, there are online services for storing data (like in-game purchases, for example). (for ios 4.x and above)

Comment: look at this old answer:

[how-to-share-custom-data-between-iphone-applications][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220630/how-to-share-custom-data-between-iphone-applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You understand (somewhat) incorrectly.  The only things that your application can save locally outside of its own sandbox are security settings in the keychain.  Your sandbox will be completely removed upon app deletion, so you need to make sure you store the data somewhere else.  Since you target below iOS 5 (makes it a pain for iCloud), the best way would be to store it on a web server.

Comment: thanks, I've heard about SFHFKeychainUtils, maybe it can help, but I'm still wondering, is there any online services, which supports storing data like that (maybe as rewards)?

Comment: @Dimon: borrrden has a valid point here. However if you could consider targeting >= iOS 5 iCloud would be THE solution for this task.

Comment: You could use Dropbox, but you might run out of space depending on how much data you store.

Comment: Can I use Dropbox as a remote storage in my apps without installing any others apps?