# Share information between apps

Tags: objective-c, ios, url-scheme

i need to share information between several apps.

For example there are 2 apps A and B.

I (as user) opened app named A. When app is lunched i want to get some info from app B.

i know that somehow this is possible with **url schemes**.

For example like login with facebook works.
Other app lunches facebook app to get login info.

Thank you.

Comment: Please refer this question. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220630/how-to-share-custom-data-between-iphone-applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can't really get data directly from a app, you could however start an other app with the a URL scheme and request data.

But you will have to either build both apps or there has to be an extensive API available for the other app.
Then the other app will have to start your app again with an app URL scheme and send the data request via the URL. But the data you can transfer this way is limited.

A good tutorial on using App URL Scheme kan be found here: http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

An other option is to store the data you want to share in between apps in the keychain. Multiple app can share a keychain item as long a they are within the same bundle seed ID.

Comment: So i should start another app with url requesting data and that should start again same app with this data ? But is this secure ?

Comment: Okay maybe you know where i could find how to use keychain between my apps ?

Comment: have a look at the [Apple Keychain Service programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/security/conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html)